# Issue with multithreading using Karate version higher than v0.9.6: http call failed after 55 milliseconds for url:

Tags: karate

I'm running a big campaign with about 500 tests targeting the API of an orchestration tool using both a parallel and a sequential runner for some of the tests which need to be executed in sequence.

This works fine using the Karate version 0.9.6.

As soon as I upgrade the Karate version to anything higher than v0.9.6, the results of the tests in the parallel runner always consists of a significant portion of failing tests. The sequential runner does not have any issues. Also the parallel runner seems to work fine only if I set it's threadCount = 1.
If the threadCount is higher than 1, the runner seems always to start well but after some time there are quite some failed transactions without any further details like this: **http call failed after 55 milliseconds for url: http://...**
This is all the error log I have as there is not more than this entry for each failed test (around 40% of the full campaign).

As soon as one thread starts with an issue like that, basically all other threads follow to do the same and make their tests fail for the same reason (only with a slightly different number of milliseconds). While investigating the problem I was not able to identify a common pattern (like always starting with the same test failing, etc.).

Did anybody else face similar issues with Multithreading using a higher version than v0.9.6?

Is there a way to get more detailed logs? I use the value DEBUG in the logback-test.xml

Is there any recommendation of what to try to make it work?

Please don't hesitate in case you need more information.
I would be happy for any kind of help regarding this as I would like to benefit of the new karate-gatling facilities for Performance Testing which is only available in the latest versions of Karate.

Many Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I'm really sorry at least I can't think of anything unless you provide a way to replicate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - other than that, see if you get any tips from this thread: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1216 - note that we spent a lot of time doing RC versions and everyone else seems to have migrated to 1.1.0 without issues

Answer (score 1):

we run 8 threads on karate 1.1.0 with no issues at all. Do you have some extra logs? So you don't get same timeout error `http call failed after 55 milliseconds for url: http://...`  in lower version the running multithreads ?

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here, but do some of your scenarios have the same title?  If so, try making them all unique and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

More logs will be useful. Its very little information here.

I am not sure of the exact error but I faced similar issues sometime ago but that was caused due to race conditions especially if you are trying to use variables set by java methods. Are you using Java interop in your tests? If so worth checking how these are being used. A test may be trying to execute with a variable/parameter that is still in use by other tests when running in parallel. This wouldn't be an issue in sequential.